# WCF - Using <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" /> but HttpContext is still null

Tags: wcf

I've also remembered to include 
`AspNetCompatibilityRequirements( RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required )]` on my service.

As far as I can tell these are the only two things that need to be set but nobody on the WCF forums seem to be able to help. I am running in IIS7. Is there something else I could be missing??

Comment: Where do you access `HttpContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it doesn't work when using Net.Tcp binding:(

Answer (score 1):

Try setting IIS application pool mode to Integrated if it is classic. Make sure it is running .NET 4.0.